# Get user browser info in Python Bottle

Tags: python, user-agent

I'm trying to find out which browsers are my users using and I'm running into a problem.
If I try to read header "User-Agent" it usually gives me lots of text, and tells me nothing.
For example, if I visit the site with Chrome, in "User-Agent" header there is:

User-Agent: "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.57 Safari/537.36".

As you can see, this tells me nothing since there is mention of Mozzila, Safari, Chrome etc.. even though I visited with Chrome.

Framework I've been using is Bottle (Python).

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I think you need to provide the code you've written.

Comment: Do you want to know in real time, or after the fact?  Huge difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your answers, I found something really simple that works.

Download httpagentparser module from:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/httpagentparser

after that, just import it in your pythong program

```
import httpagentparser
```

Then you can write a function like this that returns browser, works like a charm:

```
def detectBrowser(request):
agent = request.environ.get('HTTP_USER_AGENT')
browser = httpagentparser.detect(agent)
if not browser:
    browser = agent.split('/')[0]
else:
    browser = browser['browser']['name']  

return browser
```

That's it

Answer (score 5):

> User-Agent: "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36
>   (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.57 Safari/537.36".
>
> As you can see, this tells me nothing since there is mention of
>   Mozzila, Safari, Chrome etc.. even though I visited with Chrome.

Your conclusion above is wrong. The UA tells you many things including the type and version of the web browser.

The post below explains why `Mozilla` and `Safari` exist in Chrome's UA.

[History of the browser user-agent string](http://webaim.org/blog/user-agent-string-history/)

You can try to analyze it manually on [user-agent-string-db](http://user-agent-string.info/).

There's a [Python API](https://github.com/hamaxx/uasparser2/) for it.

```
from uasparser2 import UASparser

uas_parser = UASparser()
# Instead of fecthing data via network every time, you can cache the db in local
# uas_parser = UASparser('/path/to/your/cache/folder', mem_cache_size=1000)
# Updating data is simple: uas_parser.updateData()


result = ua_parser.parse('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.57 Safari/537.36')


# result
{'os_company': u'',
 'os_company_url': u'',
 'os_family': u'Linux',
 'os_icon': u'linux.png',
 'os_name': u'Linux',
 'os_url': u'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux',
 'typ': u'Browser',
 'ua_company': u'Google Inc.',
 'ua_company_url': u'http://www.google.com/',
 'ua_family': u'Chrome',
 'ua_icon': u'chrome.png',
 'ua_info_url': u'http://user-agent-string.info/list-of-ua/browser-detail?browser=Chrome',
 'ua_name': u'Chrome 31.0.1650.57',
 'ua_url': u'http://www.google.com/chrome'}
```

Answer (score 3):

> As you can see, this tells me nothing since there is mention of
>   Mozzila, Safari, Chrome etc.. even though I visited with Chrome.

It's not that the User Agent string tells you "nothing;" it's that it's telling you too much.

If you want a report that breaks down your users browser, your best bet is to analyze your logs.  [Several programs are available](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_analytics_software) to help.  (One caveat, if you're using Bottle's "raw" web server, is that it won't log in Common Log Format out of the box.  You have [options](http://blog.philippklaus.de/2013/06/logging-requests-with-bottle-web-applications/).)

If you need to know in real time, you'll need to spend time learning user agent strings ([useragentstring.com](http://useragentstring.com) might help here) or use an API like [this one](http://www.browserscope.org/ua).